# Templates in TeXnicCenter 2 beta 1

Tags: errors, texniccenter

[As recommended](http://www.texniccenter.org/news/153-texniccenter-2-beta-1) I have installed the TeXnicCenter 2 beta 1 over my TeXnicCenter RC 1 installation.

In principle it works quite well, but if I try to open my templates (TeXnicCenter/Templates) clicking File/New/File from Template... it is not displayed correctly. There only appear squares. This indeed seems to indicate an encoding problem. But if I call the same (!) file using File/Open/File... it is displayed correctly (it can also be compiled without any problems).

In summary: The same (!) file is displayed correctly by TeXnicCenter 2 beta 1 if opened "normally" via File/Open/File..., whereas it is buggy via File/New/File from Template...

In TeXnicCenter RC 1 this error does not occur.

Path: `C:\Programme\TeXnicCenter\Templates\Documents\Deutsch`. Filename: It happens with every template, regardless of the filename (one example: Standard.tex). Encoding: I normally use ANSI or UTF-8. In the present case: If the file is opened normally via File/Open/File... TeXnicCenter says it is UTF-8 encoded; if opened via File/New/File from Template... TeXnicCenter says it is UTF-16 encoded. This seems to be the problem, but I have no idea why TeXnicCenter uses UTF-16 if the file is opened via File/New/File from Template... and I do not know how to fix that.

It appears that I am at least not the only one having this problem, see [this report on sourceforge.net](http://sourceforge.net/tracker/?func=detail&aid=3092787&group_id=36323&atid=479426)

---

MikTeX 2.9, Windows XP.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Usually, we don't put a greeting or a "thank you" in our posts. While this might seem strange at first, it is not a sign of lack of politeness, but rather part of our trying to keep everything very concise. Upvoting is the preferred way here to say "thank you" to users who helped you.

Comment: There two problems with your contribution: First: What is your question? Second: You yourself suspect, it is a bug (and BTW it seems to me, as well), but StackExchange is not meant for bug reports. These have to go to the developer(s) on channels, where they are active, and in the case of TeXnicCenter [the channel is clearly stated](http://www.texniccenter.org/contribute/contribute).